# How to apply a grid transformation in sf with PROJ7?

Tags: grid, transform, r-sf, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I try to apply a gridded transformation of coordinates in `sf`, but it does not work. Is there something else to do apart from calling `sf_proj_network(TRUE)`? Here is the code I used:

`pt_27572 <- data.frame(X=55824.4970,Y=2394454.2120)`  # set coordinates of one point in EPSG:27572

`pt_2154 <- data.frame(X=107242.8310,Y=6832277.1820)`  # known accurate coordinates of the same point in EPSG:2154

`ptSf_27572 <- st_as_sf(pt_27572, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 27572)` # build sf object

`ptSf_2154 <- st_as_sf(pt_2154, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 2154)` # build sf object

`sf_proj_network(TRUE)`  # allow search for online datum grids in the PROJ CDN

[1] "https://cdn.proj.org"

`sf_proj_pipelines("EPSG:27572", "EPSG:2154")` # grids (fr_ign_gr3df97a.tif) seem to be found for accurate transformation from EPSG:27572 to EPSG:2154

```
Candidate coordinate operations found:  3
Strict containment:     FALSE
Axis order auth compl:  FALSE
Source:  EPSG:27572
Target:  EPSG:2154
Best instantiable operation has accuracy: 1 m
Description: Inverse of Lambert zone II + NTF (Paris) to NTF (1) + NTF to
             RGF93 (1) + Lambert-93
Definition:  +proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8
             +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=2200000
             +ellps=clrk80ign +pm=paris +step +proj=push +v_3
             +step +proj=cart +ellps=clrk80ign +step
             +proj=xyzgridshift +grids=fr_ign_gr3df97a.tif
             +grid_ref=output_crs +ellps=GRS80 +step +inv
             +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step
             +proj=lcc +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44
             +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80
```

`ptSf_2154_grid <- st_transform(ptSf_27572,crs=2154)` # apply transformation

`st_distance(ptSf_2154_grid,ptSf_2154)` # incorrect (ungridded) transformation, the distance should be zero. 3.777 m is the known error for the ungridded transformation.

```
Units: [m]
         [,1]
[1,] 3.777346
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1815. The underlying reason is a PROJ regression for versions 7.2.1-8.1.1 fixed by https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/2884.